# Electric and magnetic field operators hermiticity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I've just gone through the electromagnetic field quantization as in Milonni 1993, chap. 2. At page 41 we get the expressions for the field operators, up to constants:
$$
\mathbf{E}=a\mathbf{A}-a^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}^* \\
\mathbf{B}=a\mathbf{f}+a^{\dagger}\mathbf{f}^*
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is just a complex function (space part of vector potential),  $\mathbf{f}$ another complex function (curl of $\mathbf{A}$), $^*$ complex conjugate, $a$ a non-hermitian lowering operator, $a^{\dagger}$ its adjoint (raising operator).

Now I haven't been juggling with operators for quite a long time time, still it looks to me that $\mathbf{E}$ is anti-hermitian $\mathbf{B}$ is hermitian, correct? If so, what does it mean? Isn't the electric operator an observable?

EDIT
For future reference, the correct expression for the electric operator is
$$
\mathbf{E}=i \left( a\mathbf{A}-a^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}^* \right)
$$
which makes it hermitian.

Comment: send you a big hug =)

Comment: There should be i (imaginary unit) at the first equation. Moreover,  for a free field $|E|\propto c |B|$ (up to direction) so $\vec{B}=c\hat{k}\times\vec{E}$